# Need a pattern to capture multiple data sizes

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, interface, input, range

Something I am struggling with: a UI for Network QoS Changes.

The situation: There is a fixed maximum limit. The sum of the sub-values must not exceed this limit. Sub-values are captured as integers and represents a KB size.

The initial design looked like:

[image: The horizontal stack on top shows the maximum, category breakdown and sub-values.]

The categories sub-values can be edited by using the sider and/or fine-tuning using the numeric-spinner. (Given, it will make sense to swop the positions of the slider and the numeric-spinner).

Then comes the REAL PROBLEM: Sub-values can range from 8KB to 10000000KB (10GB)!!! Even in increments of 8 this makes for many many options.

So I tried something like:

[image: Holy Crap, Batman! That is rather ugly!]

Here i tried to segregate the KB, MB and GB to enable fine-tuning early. But it feels very unnatural.

After much much much testing and iterating it has been simplified down to:

[image: simpler version]

The Low, Medium and Large options helps get the numeric value into a 'zone' before fine-tuning with the spinner.

After further testing and iterating, the design has been reduced to:

[image: final version ... help needed]

...

Guys, I need help. Has anyone come across a better solution for this?

Is there a better way to improve the interaction on this?

Is the best way going to be to let the user input the various sub-values one-digit-at-a-time...?

Its my first real question here so Im keen for some feedback :)

Comment: Welcome to UX SE @SerenS hope we can help

Answer (score 3):

Consider separating out the number entry from the units

[image: number select]

Comment: Thanks Dave. I plan to become a more active member of this ux community.

Comment: And Thanks for your answer. I have considered something like this. It is clean and simple. But it does not cater for more granular inputs. For example if the guy wanted 1050KB on silver, he could enter 1.05MB or enter 1050KB... But i feel like this is close to the solution i seek...

So, in the spirit of good ux, I have decided to explore the data around historical changes to see what statistical spread of values users have previously commonly used...

Perhaps Im trying to cater for outlying scenarios by over engineering this :)